# Calling function in if statement or switch not working properly

Tags: c

When I compile and run this the output is:

```
press n to continue
n
Enter the filename: [ �h�� ]
```

But, if I call the *new();* directly it run perfectly. But when I call *new();* in if statement or switch statement, it shows the above output.
I tried *scanf*, *fgets* and *gets* in the *new()* fucntion but still not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int menu();
int new();

int main(){

    menu();

    return 0;
}

int menu(){
    printf("press n to continue\n");
    //char c = getc(stdin);
    char c = getchar();

   if(c=='n'){
      new();
   }
   else if(c==27){
      return 0;
   }

}

int new(){

    char filename[50];

    printf("Enter the filename: ");
    //fgets(filename, 50, stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", filename);
    printf("[ %s ]\n\n", filename); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need either `%[^\n]` or `%s` but you have mixed them.

Comment: `char c = getchar();` --> `char c = getchar();getchar();`

Comment: `menu` does not return on all path.

Comment: or even `int c = getchar()...`

Comment: Better to  use the good commented out code `fgets(filename, 50, stdin);` rather than the problematic `scanf("%[^\n]s", filename);`?  Suggest code goes back to `fgets()`.

Comment: What should `int menu()` return when `n` is read?

Comment: @chux I missed the return statement of the menu(), my bad.

Comment: @chux fgets gave the same problem. I tried that already.

Comment: @BatMan "fgets gave the same problem." are you saying `fgets(filename, 50, stdin); printf("[ %s ]\n\n", filename);` gave output like `"[ �h�� ]"` or some other output?

Comment: @chux Yes, a little different result. It return a new line or something. Output: Enter the filename: [ 
 ]

Comment: @BatMan So not really the _same_ problem.  The best solution is to use `fgets()` for all user input, even to get that `n` to continue. ... Or stay with `getchar()/scanf()` and enjoy more learning experiences.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` will read one character from stdin and leave the \n. So when you call scanf - it stops immediately and you got nothing. To skip whitespaces and start reading from non-space character add space before format.

```
scanf(" %49[^\n]", filename);
```

Do not mix %[] and %s

Always specify max number of chars to read (leaving one additional char for nul-terminator)

And compile with highest warning level - so you do not leave menu function without return.

Oh. and check the return value of scanf

```
if(scanf(" %49[^\n]", filename) == 1)
    printf("[ %s ]", filename);
```

Comment: Why do we add space? Sorry, I didn't get that. I thought scanf prompt for new input.

Comment: scanf does not prompts - it reads input buffer and parse it according to the format string. if there is not enough data in the stream it waits till user enters more data and press enter. When scanf is called in your program the input buffer contains "\n" left from the previous input. If we do not have space in format - scanf reads it - matches it against ^\n and leaves immediately living the \n in the input buffer. When we add space - scanf reads \n since it is isspace() - matches the value read against space format character and waits for next input.

Comment: When next input line is received scanf also skips all whitespaces (characters for that isspace() is true) and then starts filling filename buffer till \n is encountered or 49 chars are read.